# How to get raw binary data of an image or others files?

Tags: image-processing, binary-data

I want to get the raw binary data of an image but I don't know how to do that. Is any module available there to do that? I need some help. If anyone knows the solution to this help me.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably just with **ImageMagick** in your Terminal. Say you have a JPEG and want the RGB pixel values in binary without headers or anything:

```
magick INPUT.JPG -depth 8 RGB:output.bin
```

Or you have a PNG and want RGBA data:

```
magick INPUT.PNG -depth 8 RGBA:output.bin
```